# Luck versus Skill in Mutual Fund Returns (Fama-French 2010)

Tags: fama-french, replication, mutual-fund, crsp

I am reading carefully [Luck versus Skill in Mutual Fund Returns (Fama-French 2010)](https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/bespeneckbo/default/AFA611-Eckbo%20web%20site/AFA611-S8C-FamaFrench-LuckvSkill-JF10.pdf), and actually trying to replicate their findings. I have always found Fama-French papers well written, but they seem to never give enough details on the paper to smoothly allow for replication.

In particular, in page 1917 of the paper, the authors mention:

> Our mutual fund sample is from the CRSP (Center for Research in Security
> Prices) database. We include only funds that invest primarily in U.S. common
> stocks, and we combine, with value weights, different classes of the same fund
> into a single fund (see French (2008)). To focus better on the performance of
> active managers, we exclude index funds from all our tests.

But they do not give any details about how they identify equity mutual funds that primarily invest in U.S. common stocks. The paper they cite ([French (2008)](http://qed.econ.queensu.ca/pub/faculty/milne/322/ECON322(2008)%20Kenneth%20R%20French.pdf)) is of no much help either.

Any ideas on how to identify the equity mutual funds that primarily invest in U.S. common stocks from the CRSP Mutual Fund database?

Comment: The [tag:replication] tag does not seem to fit here (though it has no description, so we cannot know for sure).

Comment: A very rough solution would be to exclude all MFs that have the words "international" "foreign" "global" etc.  in the fund name. Traditionally US mutual funds have been very US focused, and the ones that go abroad have made that fact known in their name or description.

Comment: Actually, the paper you mention (French, 2008) discusses how to identify US funds in its appendix B. Probably not enough for exact replication, but a start.

Comment: Thanks Enrico, that is useful. Again French style, not enough for a questionless replication. Haha

Comment: I don't how familiar you are with CRSP, however, I would assume you have used most of the finance/econ databases based on your nickname. As already suggested, the CRPSP and French's paper from 2008 gives some hint along the CRSP itself: https://www.crsp.org/products/research-products/crsp-survivor-bias-free-us-mutual-funds But you already stated that those together didn't give enough information for everything to be clear-cut. Could you provide some information on what exactly you need for the replication, or what are you so far missing? Having worked in the academia previously, I used to get

Comment: ... fairly broad tasks regarding data replication and data gathering, so I don't immediately see issues about what those previous papers and links provided are lacking. But I also could provide some aid, given that I still have access to many of the databases needed.